# Why is my update query not actually updating?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have been trying out an update query with information from another table but somehow is not working and i can't figure out why it is

this is how i'm doing the query:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.sheet_expedient=db_data.sheet_expedient 
FROM dbo_expedient_reports x
INNER JOIN  db_data ON x.sheet_expedient= db_data.sheet_expedient
WHERE x.sheet_expedient IS NULL
```

why is this not working? thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

i see some people a little confused about the structure of the table, here it is

dbo_expedient_reports

```
report_id|sheet_expedient|report_number|report_date|notificacion_date|report_status|
1        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        |
2        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        |
3        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        |
4        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        |
5        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        |
6        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        |
7        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        | 
8        | NULL          | NULL        | NULL      | NULL            | NULL        |
```

db_data (this one has the information i want to put on dbo_expedient_reports)

```
  sheet_expedient|report_date|name_expedient_owner|address_expedient|
  1              | 01-01-2011|mike                | his house 123   |
  2              | 06-06-2006|josh                | their house 456 |
  3              | 07-07-2007|andrew              | his place 789   |
  4              | 08-08-2008|frank               | somewhere 1111  |
  5              | 09-09-2009|chad                | anywhere 2222   |
  6              | 10-10-2010|zack                | nowhere 3333    |
  7              | 11-11-2011|steve               | everywhere 4444 |
  8              | 12-12-2012|mark                | here      5555  |
```

The main idea is that the sheet expedient information goes to dbo_expedient reports for an instance and the other rows from db_data go another tables where the information will be placed, you may think, the sheet expedient is the same as the id, well that is not the case since the sheet_expedient gets to a limit (around 800) and then starts over again so it's different from the id, while the sheet_expedient will hit the number 800 then will start again so the id will be id 800 sheet_expedient 800 and then id 801 sheet_expedient 1

i hope a clarified some doubts for a better understanding, thanks for all of the replies

Comment: _why is this not working?..._ What exactly is not working?

Comment: hi – B001ᛦ - actually it is doing nothing, the result i obtained says 0 rows returned, meaning that actually didn't modified anything

Comment: The query is working.  If it is not doing what you expect, then there is a misunderstanding in your expectations.  Show us an example of source data, and what you expect the data to be after you execute the query, and we will be able to explain why it isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: This is never going to change the values in x.sheet_expedient because of the INNER JOIN.  The only time it will match, because of your WHERE clause, is when sheet_expedient is NULL in both of your tables.  Without the WHERE clause all of the values for sheet_expedient in both tables will still match because of the INNER JOIN and no update will occur.  I suspect that you need to JOIN on other columns, but can't really say what without seeing your table structures and sample data.

Comment: You should post sample data of both table and expected result after update.

Comment: After seeing your data, I would say that you have to join on `x.report_id = db_data.sheet_expedient`. You cannot join on `x.sheet_expedient` since it is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you have `JOIN` on the wrong column. Here is the fix.

```
UPDATE x
SET x.sheet_expedient=db_data.sheet_expedient 
FROM dbo_expedient_reports x
INNER JOIN  db_data ON x.report_id = db_data.sheet_expedient --here is the change
WHERE x.sheet_expedient IS NULL
```

Note, all this is really going to do is *duplicate* the `report_id` column. That is, the `report_id` column will match the `sheet_expedient` column for your `dbo_expedient_reports` table. I'm not sure what the point of this is.

Also, the `WHERE` clause isn't needed based on this sample data.

Comment: i have one question, if i want to update another column related to the tables that i put on example, what should i change?

Comment: you'd just add that to the `set`. So... `SET x.sheet_expedient=db_data.sheet_expedient, x.anotherColumn = db_data.anotherColumn`

Comment: yes, you are right, but for example i have a column with a larger number of data (around 1650 rows) and is just inserting 800, why does this happen?

Comment: Because your JOIN and WHERE clause limits the rows. This is very basic SQL logic

Comment: how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what would you like to achieve.
If x.sheet_expedient is expect to be NULL then why did you use it in the join?
Do you have any other fields that you can use to join the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Think you need a left join:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.sheet_expedient=db_data.sheet_expedient 
FROM dbo_expedient_reports x
LEFT JOIN  db_data ON x.sheet_expedient= db_data.sheet_expedient
WHERE x.sheet_expedient IS NULL
```

Comment: This wouldn't change anything since it's an `UPDATE`.

Comment: hi scsimon - do you mean i need to do an insert? the table called dbo_expedient_reports has only a populated column that has the ids but the rest are empty, what i basically tried to do is just populate one single column, i tried with an insert but it throws an error that i must pass a value to that id column, what can i do in that case? - thanks for your reply

Comment: @сꝛıϻѕοɴᴠᴇɴoϻ to inform the SO members about new comment use "@" before their name

Comment: hi SQL_M - i tried your query, it works, but it doesn't update, i mean, the row stills null

Comment: @B001ᛦ thanks for the advice, my bad on tagging, i'm new here (maybe less than 2 weeks)

Comment: no problem, just wanted to make your SO-life a bit easier :) @сꝛıϻѕοɴᴠᴇɴoϻ

Answer (score 0):

To check try this:

```
WITH cte AS
    (SELECT         x.sheet_expedient       [FieldToUpdate]
     ,              db_data.sheet_expedient [NewValue]
     ,              *
       FROM         dbo_expedient_reports x
      INNER JOIN    db_data ON x.sheet_expedient = db_data.sheet_expedient
      WHERE         x.sheet_expedient IS NULL)
--UPDATE  cte    SET  [FieldToUpdate] = [NewValue];
SELECT  *   FROM  cte;
```

I usually wrap my updates into a cte before running them.  Allows me to see values before and values after.  While this won't answer your question, it should help you identify why.

I've commented out the update statement, once the select is returning the rows and values you expect, uncomment the update, and comment out the select.

Comment: i tried your code and it shows an error, says "sheet_expedient" was specified multiple times

Comment: Try expanding out the * and then remove the duplicate column name.